# How can we build a view of nodes with their redirect source URLs shown in it?

Tags: 8, views, redirection

I want to build a view of nodes with their redirect source URLs along with node titles. However a direct relationship cannot be established as they do not have a common reference.

Comment: Build a view that gets the redirect information you need. Then build a view of nodes, and display the first view within each row.

Comment: You could use [views_field_view](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) to accomplish what @sonfd said.